# What does this line do in PyQt5?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I've been trying to learn PyQt5 and GUI development in Python. I used QtDesigner to design my window, and then exported the *.ui* file into a *.py* file through pyuic5. In my **Main.py** file, I then load the GUI through a class :

```
class MainMenu(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.setupUi(window)
        self.boutonDemarrer.clicked.connect(self.demarrer)
        self.boutonArret.clicked.connect(self.arreter)
    def demarrer(self):
        activerMain()
    def arreter(self):
        sys.exit()
```

Then, in my **Main.py** code, I have these lines which show the GUI when I start the program :

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = MainMenu(MainWindow)
widget.addWidget(MainWindow)
widget.setFixedWidth(960)
widget.setFixedHeight(540)
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

My question is, what does the `ui = MainMenu(MainWindow)` do in this context? It seems to create an instance of the class *MainMenu*, but I'm not sure why, since it's not this *ui* object that we show at the end, it's the *MainWindow*. Can someone help me understand what's going on here?

Comment: Where did you take that syntax? You should subclass by inheriting from QMainWindow *and* Ui_MainWindow, subclassing from Ui_MainWindow alone is pointless (and discouraged). You should also not normally add a QMainWindow (or a QDialog) to a QStackedWidget, as they are intended as *top level widgets*.

Comment: I would guess you should have your own subclass of `QMainWindow` and put that line in its `__init__` function.

Comment: This link hass an example at the end that demonstrates what @musicamante is saying about inheriting from QMainWindow along with your UI window: https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/first-steps-qt-creator/

Comment: I'm not sure why, since it's not this ui object that we show at the end, it's the MainWindow. ..... I though you were showing widget (QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()) , or am I wrong ?